# android Admob configChanges

Tags: android, admob

I'm using Admobsdk 4.3.1. When I built the program for android 2.3 it was working but I got an error message instead of the ads,  requesting the following

ConfigChanges = keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize.

In order to compile I was forced to change target build from 2.3 to 3.2. I have also changed the minSdk to 2.3 and the program works on gingerbread like this. However I figure on a device using 2.3 it will be impossible to receive any ads.

So now I would like to switch to an older version of the admob jar. Does anyone know if this will work and where can I find an older version? On admob site there is only the latest one.

Thanks in advance.
Matt

Answer (score 2):

AdMob SDK 4.3.1 requires the following config changes, and the following config changes require you to change the build target to 3.2 or higher.  You can still use AdMob on any emulators or devices down to Android 1.5 by specifying:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

If your app only runs on Android 2.3 or higher, you would set minSdkVersion to 9.  Note that the build target is only the version of Android used to compile your app.  AdMob will run on lower versions of Android, just test to make sure that your app works fine on these lower versions as well.

Please see this [blog post](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html) for more information about using 4.3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I have it a little clearer now. However I still don't understand why I cannot run the app in debug mode on my device which has 2.3 installed. I must create a virtual device with 3.2.

Comment: That's odd, it should be able to run both in debug mode on your 2.3 device, and on an emulator with Android 2.3.  Is this a runtime error or a compilation error?

Comment: The program compiles, but I can't get to runtime. I'm using eclipse, I do the following: Run -> Run Configurations; Set it to manual, and at that point I need to select the real device on which to run it from a list of connected devices.I can see my phone is on line but since the Android version is different I can't select it. Eclipse says:"select a device compatible with target android 4.0"

Comment: Actually it works, I hadn't tried to actually select it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Eclipse places a red X next to the emulator/device if the device version is different than the target version, but as long as it's greater than the minSdkVersion, it will run.  Glad you've figured it out.